# Which SQL Query is Better?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, linq-to-sql, database

Is this SQL query statement:

```
SELECT p.id, p.[name], SUM(ps.sales_amount) AS GROSS_SALES
FROM products p
  LEFT OUTER JOIN product_sales ps ON p.id = ps.product_id
GROUP BY p.id, p.[name]
```

better than:

```
SELECT SUM([t2].[value]) AS [SalesAmount], [t2].[id] AS [ProductId], [t2].[name] AS [ProductName]
FROM (
    SELECT (
        SELECT SUM([t1].[sales_amount])
        FROM [dbo].[product_sales] AS [t1]
        WHERE [t1].[product_id] = [t0].[id]
        ) AS [value], [t0].[id], [t0].[name]
    FROM [dbo].[products] AS [t0]
    ) AS [t2]
GROUP BY [t2].[id], [t2].[name]
```

The second one is a result of a LINQ2SQL query. Still finding a way to re-write the LINQ expression...

What would be the most optimized SQL query in the example?

Your thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Don't have SQL Profiler installed... unfortunately

Comment: You don't need Profiler. Just use SET SHOWPLAN_TEXT before you run the query.

Comment: or press ctrl-K (or ctrl-M, I dont remember)

Comment: the first one will cost less to maintain

Comment: @dan - not really. The 2nd one is generated. It will cost much less.

Comment: FYI, the way to perform a `LEFT JOIN` in Linq to SQL is to use `DefaultIfAny()`.

Comment: @codekaizen Wow i didn't know about. SET SHOWPLAN_TEXT.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real answer is that you can't tell without measuring.  Even then you don't really know unless you measure on a realistic dataset.

Check out this [blog post](http://blog.codeville.net/2007/12/13/outsmarted-by-linq-to-sql/) (not by me) where the generated sql looked worse but performed much better.  His example specifically deals with subselects vs joins so I think it is very relevant to your situation.

Comment: The `LEFT JOIN/IS NULL` mistake is a common one.  It prevents SQL Server from performing an anti semi join and almost never performs as well as people think it does.  It's good to keep in mind but doesn't really apply here, as this is not an anti join.

Comment: True. This isn't about an anti-semi-join, but what I took from the blog post was that sometimes the optimizer and/or LINQ is smarter than I am. :) I think that could apply here.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the first query is better because it is more readable.  However, since the second query was generated than that explains it and since you won't (shouldn't) have to deal with the actual SQL generated from the LINQ expression there probably isn't a problem with the second one.

I would assume that the SQL Server engine can flatten that out into a standard join like the first query.  If you want to know fire up SQL Server Management Studio and look at the actual execution plan of both.

Answer (score 1):

As a general statement this seems like a fairly abusive subquery, and on that basis I'd predict that the first query will be faster. Why not try them and see?

Answer (score 1):

That first one is more efficient.  In general joins are better than subqueries.  MS-sql does not always optimize subqueries to their logical "join" equivalents.  The query is so small though that either should be reasonably good, and it will probably make no difference.  You'll need to look at the **query plan** to see the difference, or look at both being executed using a **trace**.

The first is also of course more readable.  This is what you will tend to get with Linq-to-SQL these days.  Of course, the whole point is that you shouldn't have to deal with the sql yourself.

The story is that the queries generated by Linq-to-Sql will get more and more efficient.

Comment: Did you actually check to see what SQL Server did with the second query?

Comment: You can't really say that without knowing how the query-rewriter and optimizer in this case work

Comment: No, one can't know for sure unless one checks, which is why I (and most everyone else) suggested an actual check.  There are other factors.  Are there indexes?  Are there covered indexes?  What about when it moves to 2008?  The *size* of these tables will affect sql's indexing/optimizing decisions.  I'm happy with my answer, but I'd need to be sitting at his machine to really compare.  Is that what we all do, for every query?  Go through extensive analysis?  No, we don't.  We make our best guess based on knowledge & experience, and move on.  1st one is probably better, if it matters, check.

Answer (score 1):

My hunch is that both should be the same, performance-wise.  The left join is probably going to be a nested loop join, which is exactly what the subquery version will do.

But don't take my word for it - as everyone else is suggesting, check out the execution plan and see for yourself which one is better.  Or turn on client statistics and see which one takes longer.